# Keyboard/Mouse not working after installation from windows

Tags: 12.04, keyboard, mouse

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 from Windows 7 via windows installer. It completed (I guess) successfully.

The problem occurs when I start Ubuntu. Neither mouse nor keyboard work (both usb). I can't type in the password.

Sorry if the question is a duplicate.

update: Keyboard and Mouse work on USB 3.0 ports but not on others. What should I do? I don't want to waste 3.0 on keyboard and mouse.

Comment: Thank you very much Invader Zim! I have been having this issue for some time now and this resolved it, I have a Gigabyte motherboard :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try different USB ports?

If they all do not work, try to SSH into your machine. If you have access to your home router, you can see what computers are connected with their IPs. Check your

```
ls /dev/input/by-id/
```

to see if your USBs are even detected. You will see the names of your devices attached. If they are not there, this may be a USB driver issue.

Update:

OP has a new Gigabyte motherboard that has an option called IOMMU which is disabled by default. Enabling it solves the problem.

Comment: I tried different USB ports although they all work (just to be sure). Keyboard and mouse fail to work only when I choose Ubuntu, otherwise they work (Windows, BIOS etc).

I'm new to Ubuntu (and Linux). Checking if USBs are detected should be done from Ubuntu? Because I can't do anything in Ubuntu, I'm stuck at the log in screen

Comment: Do you have more than one computer? Also, can you boot into recovery mode?

Comment: I have one computer. I don't know if I can boot into recovery mode

Comment: You don't know how to or you can't?

Comment: I've never done it. I'll go to a different computer to be on this question and will try to to boot into recovery mode on this machine.

Comment: Hold the left `shift` right after BIOS. You should see the GRUB menu where you can see the OSes on your harddrive. Select advanced options and then select the one with recovery mode.

Comment: Went to recovery mode, keyboard didn't work in recovery menu. Found the solution.

There is a BIOS option called IOMMU Controller with newer Gigabyte motherboards, and it is disabled by default. Enabling it solves the problem.

I should have done more research. Found the solution here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72625/why-is-usb-not-working-in-linux-when-it-works-in-uefi-bios

Sorry for wasting your time. Can you please post the above as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Good to hear, no time wasted, I learned something new too.